# Codeigniter query count() total comments joining three tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am attempting to create a query to get a single blog post from my blog table and at the same time get the information from that user on my users' table which was ok using `Join` but now I want to count the total comments of that blog post as total so that would be three tables to query `blog, users and comments`

But below code display 3 blog entry with the same content, and where to place the COUNT(*) as total for comment table, any suggestion would be great!

```
public function get_entry(){

        $id = $this->input->post('ID', true);


        $this->db->select('*, u.ID');
        $this->db->where('u.ID', $id)
         ->from('gb_blod as u')
         ->join('gb_users as a', 'u.user_email = a.email', 'LEFT')
         ->join('gb_comments as b', 'u.ID = b.journal_id', 'LEFT');
         $result = $this->db->get();


            if($result->num_rows() > 0){

            return $result->result_array();


            }else{

                return false;
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count the comment id and group the query by blog id.

```
public function get_entry(){

        $id = $this->input->post('ID', true);


        $this->db->select('u.*, a.*, count(b.ID) as total');
        $this->db->where('u.ID', $id)
         ->from('gb_blod as u')
         ->join('gb_users as a', 'u.user_email = a.email', 'LEFT')
         ->join('gb_comments as b', 'u.ID = b.journal_id', 'LEFT')
         ->group_by('u.ID');
         $result = $this->db->get();


            if($result->num_rows() > 0){

            return $result->result_array();


            }else{

                return false;
            }

    }
```

Comment: So that where you put the `count()` thank how can I query all blogs? this query returns only 1 result

Comment: Remove the where condition from the query $this->db->where('u.ID', $id)

Comment: Yes I did that but its still returning a single result which is the first one

Comment: the id you are getting in the post is the user id?

Answer (score 2):

Try using this, you can change the query according to your requirement:-

```
  $usr_flds = "count(u.ID) as count_rows";
  $this->db->select('usr_flds');
  $this->db->where('u.ID', $id)
 ->from('gb_blod as u')
 ->join('gb_users as a', 'u.user_email = a.email', 'LEFT')
 ->join('gb_comments as b', 'u.ID = b.journal_id', 'LEFT');
   $result = $this->db->get();
   return $res->num_rows();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.i hope it will work for you.

```
$result = $this->db->get();
 $count = $result->get()->num_rows();
        return [$result, $count];
```

Comment: I got an error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::get()`